# Column identified in an update from a returned value

Tags: sql, oracle

I trying to update one table with column variable.
Example:

```
Table: BILLING (ORIGIN OF DATA)
Columns: 
- CUSTOMER
- PERIOD
- REVENUE

TABLE: BILLING_MONTHLY
Columns:
- CUSTOMER
- M201301 (this value is REVENUE per year/month)
- M201302 (this value is REVENUE per year/month)
- M201303 (this value is REVENUE per year/month)
```

I need update BILLING_MONTHLY with value column of BILLING (PERIOD), but I don't achieve set column in update equal result in select of table BILLING.

Example:

Table BILLING

```
CUSTOMER    PERIOD  REVENUE
05031       201301  1000
05013       201301  550
05031       201302  800
05032       201303  930
05031       201303  880
```

Expected Result

Table BILLING_MONTHLY

```
CUSTOMER    M201301         M201302         M201303
05013       550
05031       1000            800             880
05032                                       930
```

My idea:
1) Create "FOR" to insert customer in BILLING_MONTHLY; 
2) Create "UPDATE" for valorize customer per year/month;

The problem: I don’t' obtain a update functionally due result be the column.

To create a survey:

```
CREATE TABLE BILLING
(
 CUSTOMER  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
 PERIOD    VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
 REVENUE   NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO BILLING (CUSTOMER, PERIOD, REVENUE) VALUES ('05031', '201301', 1000);
INSERT INTO BILLING (CUSTOMER, PERIOD, REVENUE) VALUES ('05013', '201301', 550);
INSERT INTO BILLING (CUSTOMER, PERIOD, REVENUE) VALUES ('05031', '201302', 800);
INSERT INTO BILLING (CUSTOMER, PERIOD, REVENUE) VALUES ('05032', '201303', 930);
INSERT INTO BILLING (CUSTOMER, PERIOD, REVENUE) VALUES ('05031', '201303', 880);
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE BILLING_MONTH
(
  CUSTOMER  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
  M201301   NUMBER,
  M201302   NUMBER,
  M201303   NUMBER
);
```

Can someone help me, please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to redesign your tables. That `BILLING_MONTHLY` is all wrong.

Comment: Now the tables are certain, thanks for tip "gvee".

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want

```
select customer, sum(c1) M201301, sum(c2) M201302, sum(c3) M201303

from(
select customer,
case when period='201301' then revenue else 0 end 'C1',
case when period='201302' then revenue else 0 end 'C2',
case when period='201303' then revenue else 0 end 'C3'
from billing
) t

group by customer
```

You need to control the **range of month** and the **name of column** of the result yourself. If this query is a part of coding, you can let the code handle that

sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aa98/13

Comment: Must update the columns per client, however, the months in table BILLING_MONTH are the values in table BILLING. When I try to do the update, I can't reference the column to extract value, because the column name M201303 (for example) must be referenced to the customer and the period, only that at the update, the column would have to be variable and not fixed. You Understand?

Comment: Your example is good, however, I have the data already in a table and are relevant to more than 3 years (40 months). With the _CASE_ the _SELECT_ will be very large and will have to be adjusted where. If I use a table with several years already identified if get tow the values the columns, I do not get by modifying the commands

Comment: This is the select used for extract values: SELECT PERIOD, CUSTOMER, SUM(VALUES_INVOICE) REVENUE
  FROM BILLING 
 GROUP BY PERIOD, CUSTOMER

Comment: `'C1'` is not a valid column alias, it's String literal. Object names need to be quoted using double quotes `"` in standard SQL (and in Oracle which is what the OP is using).